Planning a network infrastructure with redundancy
I am planning to improve my network infrastructure.
It currently consists of the following elements:

HV - Dell PowerEdge R7525 with VMware
older HV as backup
arrays - 2x QNAP TS-1279U-RP
Veeam backup

Currently, in the event of an HV failure I would have to restore machines from the backup to the backup HV, which would take a lot of time, so it would paralyze the company for some time and I would lose some data. The array failure should not cause a tragedy because it synchronizes via RTRR, but I can also lose some unsynchronized data here.
Taking into account the above, the infrastructure improvement is aimed at maintaining the operation of systems in the event of a failure of any device, as much as possible.
My planned improvement:
My infrastructure after the changes would consist of the following elements:

2x HV Dell PowerEdge R7525 with VMware
2x switch - Cisco C1300-12XS
2x array - QNAP TS-h1886XU-RP

Device configuration with redundancy:

HVs - connected in HA - when one of them fails, the other should automatically turn on
the virtual machines
arrays - configured Active-Active iSCSI Target real-time synchronization so that the
failure of any of the arrays does not result in data loss
switches - stacked and when one of them fails, the other takes over and the connection of devices according to the scheme still allows the entire system to operate. HVs, thanks to the configured Multipath I/O (MPIO), switch to the still operating, active network path


Please evaluate how I planned it.
Is this a realistic, good plan?
Am I making any mistakes in this?
Can it be done better / more economically?
.
